# Emmet-ls options won't work in nvim(nvchad)

Tags: neovim, emmet, nvim-lspconfig, neovim-plugin

**lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua:**

```lua
lspconfig.emmet_ls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  filetypes = {
    "css",
    "eruby",
    "html",
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "less",
    "sass",
    "scss",
    "svelte",
    "pug",
    "typescriptreact",
    "vue",
  },
  init_options = {
    html = {
      options = {
        -- For possible options, see: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/src/config.ts#L79-L267
        ["output.selfClosingStyle"] = "xhtml",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

**index.tsx:**

```
input /// clicking enter in completion list -----> <input type="text">
```

i copied this configuration and i edited it according to the reference of emmet-ls in github.

can someone help me with this please.

i was expecting emmet-ls to give me  `<input type="text" />` instead of `<input type="text">`
i even tried to change the *html* word inside *init_options* to *typescriptreact* but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `emmet_ls` package?

`npm install -g emmet-ls`

I've been looking for an Emmet configuration for nvim and tried the one you suggested. Once I installed emmet-ls, it began to work

Comment: I use Mason to install packages on installed emmet-ls with it but the only thing that did not work is setting the self closing style, otherwise the LS is working.

Comment: I think I realize why now, the init options seems to take keys that equal the filetypes so the config listed above is only for html.